# Double click works in Firefox but not chrome (Python/Selenium)

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium

I have an element that requires a `double_click().perform()` action. It works great in Firefox, but doesn't in Chrome. A single click displays a menu, but a double click takes you to a directory. Here is my python/selenium step:

```
(webdriver.ActionChains(self.browser)).double_click(self.browser.find_element_by_id('nav-link-shopall')).perform()
```

The error message returns that the text I'm wanting to verify exists does not exist. Which is true if the `double_click().perform()` doesn't do its job.

I'm using Python 2.7.8 and Selenium 2.45.0.

I'm using Amazon.com as an example because the behavior is the same as the proprietary code I am testing. So here is the HTML code I'm attempting to click:

```
<div class="nav-left">
    <div id="nav-shop">
         <a href="/gp/site-directory/ref=nav_shopall_btn" class="nav-a nav-a-2" data-nav-tabindex="15" id="nav-link-shopall" tabindex="1">
             <span class="nav-line-1">Shop by</span>
             <span class="nav-line-2">"Department"
                 <span class="nav-icon nav-arrow" style="visibility:visible;"></span>
             </span>
         </a>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
variable =  self.browser.find_element_by_id('nav-link-shopall')
actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.move_to_element(variable)
actions.double_click(variable)
actions.perform()
```

You should use move to element.

Comment: No, still does not work. It still works in Firefox, but for some reason it isn't performing the `double_click(variable)' in Chrome. I might add, that the Traceback is just saying `NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element` in trying to assert that the next element is present. No errors for this specific action.

Comment: Try to add build() method to it.

Comment: I feel like I'm about to ask a dumb question, but what `from` `import` do you use for build()?

Comment: As you mentioned NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element, try to use other locater instead of "id", and build comes in actions class, no need to import anything, it good to provide the html snippet

Comment: That Traceback is linked to the code that is supposed to be found on the destination page. It has nothing to do with the clicking portion of the test. It is a result of the expected results. In Firefox, my test works. The issue is that it is not working in Chrome. The `double_click().perform()` is fine in Firefox.

Comment: your code is fine, There's some issue for double click on chrome, I tried too, Please use java script executor to handle this.